# Render live preview of offscreen NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, macos-carbon

Mission Control and Exposé are capable of displaying a live (usually scaled down) preview of an NSWindow. I want to do the same thing, or at least figure out exactly how they do. Decompiling Mission Control binary revealed very little, which leads me to believe that the significant logic is somewhere else (given the multiple references to "com.apple.windowserver," likely closely coupled with the window server).

Comment: Mission Control is not capturing a stream. That's the actual window being drawn by the window server at a scaled-down size. Anyway, Apple's documentation for how to this is at: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1740/_index.html

Comment: I figured that was the case. That's what I really want to do (seriously less overhead). No matter how tricky... any ideas on how I could achieve the same thing (draw a small version of the window? Some kind of kernel extension? Or code injection into the window server?

Comment: Are you trying to record it or stream it elsewhere? There are some API limitations. Technically speaking many things are possible but may not have an API available.

Comment: I'm trying to display the contents, live, of an offscreen window, in the corner of the screen. Open to using private APIs, or hacky methods, if that makes any difference.